# Finding the ID of a gmail message

Tags: gmail-api

I'm currently playing around with the Gmail API.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Does anyone know how to find the email ID?

Thanks!

Comment: And just to test things quickly, if you open a particular email in gmail web app, it will show message id in url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do a list as described here first (it has search semantics in the q parameter if you are not interested in all messages): https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

This returns a list of messages which look like this:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource

The message id is the id field ("id": string)

Comment: Ahh ok! For some reason the "Try it now" isn't loading. I'll keep trying and see if it works! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to get  from email id ?

Answer (score 5):

To find message id you need to open message, press "..." -> Show original.
There will be message ID. But it's in weird format what Gmail API does not understand.